# Less compiler generating empty rule

Tags: html, css, less

Less input:

```css
.className1{
  /* comment */
  .className2{
    height: 50rem;
  }
  .className3{
    width: 3rem;
  }
}
```

CSS output:

```css
.className1 {
  /* comments */
}
.className1 .className2 {
  height: 50rem;
}
.className1 .className3 {
  width: 3rem;
}
```

Is there an option in less compiler which prevents generating empty css rule like above? or is this a bug or this works as designed by less?

Comment: it's not a bug it's a feature

Comment: you can use post clean up (npm clean-css as example)

Comment: also you should have your less rules list - something like https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/tree/ruleset.js - it is possible to change rules there but not easy.

Comment: and try to remove /* comment */

Comment: Or use Less `// comment` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use `/* comment  */` for commenting

you create css comment and less compiler will forced show them in output

but if you create comment with `// comment` as JavaScript comment

less compiler can ignore it